# Drools - How to check conflict between rules en XLSX?

Tags: drools, rules

At first i want to say that im not an expert in Drools, actually im worked with a Rule Engine but is based in Oracle BPM/RN.

In this technology i can if any rule have a conflict with each others:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzFvX.png)

But, i can see the same in Drools. Actually im doing a testing app with this Excel Decision Table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOJgH.png)

I select two rules that have conflicts.

Thanks in advice.

Im expected any view to check if i have any conflict between rules in XLS Decision Table.

Comment: Why do you consider those rules in conflict? They have the same conditions, but that isn't necessarily a bug.

Comment: I consider that two rules is in conflict when with any input you can resolve same rules. I mean if you have a rule with one condition, for example "field = A", and other rule with "field dont care", the rule engine if you push "A" execute two rules, and you have two different output for same input. When this happens, BPM say that you have a conflict and give you the option to override one rules, or priorice one rule, but in Excel Decision Table dont have this option to check if have a conflict.

Comment: Sure, because it's not necessarily a _conflict_. You might be doing it intentionally. If your rules have salience, that's the order they will be applied; if they don't, then it'll be the order loaded.